# TypeScript declare static enum on React.FunctionalComponent

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a React.FunctionalComponent that has static props, i.e.:

```
import MyAwesomeComponent from './MyAwesomeComponent';

...

<MyAwesomeComponent mode={MyAwesomeComponent.modes.superAwesome} />
```

Static props are key-value maps:

```
MyAwesomeComponent.modes = {
    superAwesome: 'super-awesome',
    almostAwesome: 'almost-awesome',
    regular: 'regular',
}
```

How can I write .d.ts for such components?

I tried making enum and then add to export as StaticProps:

```
enum modes {
    superAwesome = 'super-awesome',
    almostAwesome = 'almost-awesome',
    regular = 'regular',
}

interface MyAwesomeComponentProps {
    mode: modes,
}

interface StaticProps {
    modes: Record<modes, modes>,
}

declare const MyAwesomeComponent: React.FC<MyAwesomeComponentProps> & StaticProps;
export default MyAwesomeComponent;
```

But it fails on mode-values that have dashes, i.e. 'super-awesome'

How can I type such components so I can use camelCase keys and see dashed value when I move my pointer over?

**UPD**: Solution found! Thank you, aleksey-l!

**UPD2**: Some of my components are declared as a functions, i.e:

```
declare namespace MyAwesomeComponent {
    declare enum modes {
        superAwesome = 'super-awesome',
        almostAwesome = 'almost-awesome',
        regular = 'regular',
    }
}

interface MyAwesomeComponentProps {
    mode: MyAwesomeComponentProps.modes,
}

declare function MyAwesomeComponent(props: PropsWithChildren<MyAwesomeComponentProps): JSX.Element;

export default MyAwesomeComponent;
```

And I get `@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment` and `@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access` eslint errors when I try to

```
<MyAwesomeComponent mode={MyAwesomeComponent.modes.superAwesome} />
```

Comment: You might not need an enum; would a union of strings (`type modes = 'super-awesome' | 'almost-awesome' | 'regular'`) do the job?

Comment: But my JS code that I cant change has exported modes with camelCased keys

Comment: What do you mean by "fails"? Seems to work fine (after removing redundant `=` from enum definition) https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AocpAOwFc8QIATJAZzgG9y4e5XawSKAEEA7m1xI4AXgL9BUALQpxrSfgA03XigA2jVjDESQU2fj0GYy1eq284RAOa1dKKDILPX7zeQC+lMDUMEKY6FIAsgCexmqmAMK4kNQ0MAAKOGDsXA6MLABccPlsWoHkwaFQ4WhSAMowKDDAaJkQ2ZzaPCWsRcho0EwAPD0axcxsAHxllCxobkRwA9SGcDFxkkngEKkhfcQwAHQAYglD67aJyTtpbdmTcABkcA1NLXesFEgAHpCwcCxwq54BcTEgtik0qQgA

Comment: Redundant = isnt in my code - just a typo; 

The main problem is: exported static prop has MyAwesomeComponent.modes['super-awesome'] instaed of MyAwesomeComponent.modes.superAwesome; 

I need to declare existing module to use it in my .tsx code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Record<modes, modes>` produces a type with `mode` values (`'super-awesome' | 'almost-awesome' | 'regular'`) both as a keys and values. What you're looking for is the actual type of enum object which can be queried with `typeof` operator:

```
interface StaticProps {
    modes: typeof modes,
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AocpAOwFc8QIATJAZzgG9y4e5XawSKAEEA7m1xI4AXgL9BUALQpxrSfgA03XigA2jVjDESQU2fj0GYy1eq284RAOa1dKKDILPX7zeQC%20lMDUMEKY6FIAsgCexmqmAMK4kNQ0MAAKOGDsXA6MLABccPlsWoHkwaFQ4WhSAMowKDDAaJkQ2ZzaPCWsRTDRghCYxcylAZQsaG5EcGgQ1IZwMXGSSeDzaUXI6DAAdABiCQA8y7aJyRshbdkAfHAAZHANTS3XrBRIAB6QsHAs4a54KcTEg1ik0hRyMD4qCLqkQrsert5EIVqYobEzrD1vC9kjLBBDGikBjiWDLnjRqxdt5pkA)

---

Another option just for reference - using regular type alias:

```
type Modes = {
    superAwesome: 'super-awesome',
    almostAwesome: 'almost-awesome',
    regular: 'regular',
}

interface MyAwesomeComponentProps {
    mode: Modes[keyof Modes],
}

interface StaticProps {
    modes: Modes,
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AocmATzCTgFkIATJAZzgF44BvcuAXDYBXOlACCAd3a4kALgIixAWhTS2s-ABp%20glABsQENjCkyQ8ggaMnV6zTsFwiAc2H6UUBYSRuPUbXIAX0pgADsYJChMdHoGajMNCwBhXEgwpAiABRwwDj4nI1YFJlY2AG0AayRqCExGFnYAXR0Q8nDI6Ni4AGUYFBhgNByIPN5dASL2Esa2VspWNH96NAgwk0YE%20xS0tcyYBWR0GAA6ADFkgB54xNlU8D3s3LYAPjgAMl7%20weHniiQAB6QWBwVgxdzwG7bJD3dL7CjkKHmGG7DIRE5TNgnJRRW4WRFbZGwx6nTEnazGUzQgl4lEPNGk2YnVzuTxAA)

Comment: Can you also help with components that declared as a functions? (I updated question)